# Why does double brackets notation escape strings in bash?

Tags: bash

Given the following example code:

```
var="foo"
if [[ ${var} != 'bar' ]]; then...
```

If you run this piece of code in bash debug mode (`bash -x`), it reads out as follows:

```
[[ foo != \b\a\r ]]
```

It still passes correctly, but why does it show the escapes? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -x` ignores your particular method of escaping and quoting, and constructs its own equivalent representation of your strings. You shouldn't care about the exact format.

`'bar'` and `\b\a\r` encodes the exact same string, and that's what matters.

Comment: is there a better way then to test against a string? or is that the best?

Comment: That's the best and correct way to test against a string. Note, though, that when the right-hand side is a variable, it has to be quoted (unlike the left-hand side).